# Attack on server CentOs

Tags: security, cpanel, code-injection, centos7

I have checked /etc/logs/error_log and found that :

***Step one :*** **a vulnerability test was done via acunetix.com** :

{[Tue May 16 14:23:39.954825 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 24692:tid 140230707291904] AH02032: Hostname domaine.com provided via SNI and hostname www.acunetix.wvs provided via HTTP have no compatible SSL setup}

**And lines like :**

```
[Tue May 16 14:39:20.961494 2017] [core:error] [pid 24787:tid 140230858360576] [client 105.155.95.29:8493] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET /../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd/reset HTTP/1.1, referer: https://domaine.com/
```

***Step two :*** 200 mails have Been sent from contact form (haven't integrate recaptcha) with Example :

```
Nom: %2fetc%2fpasswd / Email: sample@email.tst / Message: 20
Nom: vdpaafxb / Email: sample@email.tst / Message: W49ztm2m';select pg_sleep(12); --
```

***Step three :*** i received 4 reports :

**1 -** lfd on server.xxx: System Integrity checking detected a

```
modified system file
/usr/bin/ghostscript: FAILED
/usr/bin/gs: FAILED
/bin/ghostscript: FAILED
/bin/gs: FAILED
```

**2 -** lfd on server.xxx: High 5 minute load average alert - 6.11

```
Time:                    Tue May 16 14:42:17 2017 +0100
1 Min Load Avg:          8.46
5 Min Load Avg:          6.11
15 Min Load Avg:         3.19
Running/Total Processes: 11/358
With 4 files
PS.txt  vmstat.txt  netstat.txt  apachstatus.html
```

**3 -** lfd on server.xxx: LOCALRELAY Alert for domaine

```
Time:  Tue May 16 14:52:14 2017 +0100
Type:  LOCALRELAY, Local Account - domaine
Count: 101 emails relayed
Blocked: No
Sample of the first 10 emails:
```

**4 -** lfd on server.xxx: Script Alert for

```
'/home/domaine/public_html/domaine/public'
Time:  Tue May 16 14:52:14 2017 +0100
Path:  '/home/domaine/public_html/domaine/public'
Count: 101 emails sent
Sample of the first 10 emails:
2017-05-16 14:51:34 cwd=/home/domaine/public_html/domaine/public 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
2017-05-16 14:51:34 cwd=/home/domaine/public_html/domaine/public 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
2017-05-16 14:51:34 cwd=/home/domaine/public_html/domaine/public 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
2017-05-16 14:51:34 cwd=/home/domaine/public_html/domaine/public 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
2017-05-16 14:51:34 cwd=/home/domaine/public_html/domaine/public 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
2017-05-16 14:51:34 cwd=/home/domaine/public_html/domaine/public 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
2017-05-16 14:51:35 cwd=/home/domaine/public_html/domaine/public 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
2017-05-16 14:51:35 cwd=/home/domaine/public_html/domaine/public 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
2017-05-16 14:51:35 cwd=/home/domaine/public_html/domaine/public 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
2017-05-16 14:51:35 cwd=/home/domaine/public_html/domaine/public 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
Possible Scripts:
```

***And finaly that was sent later in the same day After a cpanel update***

```
lfd on server.xxx: System Integrity checking detected a modified system file
Time:     Thu May 18 00:50:21 2017 +0100
```

The following list of files have FAILED the md5sum comparison test. This means that the file has been changed in some way. This could be a result of an OS update or application upgrade. If the change is unexpected it should be investigated:

```
/usr/bin/ab: FAILED
/usr/bin/htdbm: FAILED
/usr/bin/htdigest: FAILED
/usr/bin/htpasswd: FAILED
/usr/bin/httxt2dbm: FAILED
/usr/bin/logresolve: FAILED
/usr/sbin/fcgistarter: FAILED
/usr/sbin/htcacheclean: FAILED
/usr/sbin/httpd: FAILED
/usr/sbin/rotatelogs: FAILED
/usr/sbin/suexec: FAILED
/bin/ab: FAILED
/bin/htdbm: FAILED
/bin/htdigest: FAILED
/bin/htpasswd: FAILED
/bin/httxt2dbm: FAILED
/bin/logresolve: FAILED
/sbin/fcgistarter: FAILED
/sbin/htcacheclean: FAILED
/sbin/httpd: FAILED
/sbin/rotatelogs: FAILED
/sbin/suexec: FAILED
/usr/local/bin/passwd: FAILED
```

Knowing that the WS attacked is developed with php framework : Laravel 5.2
Don't know what happens or how to know if the server is reachable and the attacker Can do anything anytime he wants ...
Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should scan your home folder **/home/domaine/public_html/** using a malware scanner. One option would be maldet from RXFN. Another option would be ISPProtect which allows you an initial free scan (after that, it requires licensing). Also you could scan your website via web using Sucuri's online scanner https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

I am pretty sure that there are some malicious files inside your cPanel account so this allows the attacker to send emails.

It's normal to get those notifications after a cPanel update. Some files are replaced during the update so new files will have different md5 hashes compared to the old files. CSF sees that and sends you a notification.

The LFD script alert tells you that emails were sent from that cpanel user's account (most probably spam). Since they were sent using a malicious script and using php mail() function, you could manually disable the mail() function for that account just to be sure that no more mails are sent until you find the compromised files. You can also install ConfigServer Mail Manage WHM plugin (it's free) so you can set a limit for outgoing emails on that account. Set the limit to 1 email to prevent spam sending.

It's hard to say what security flaw was exploited by the attacker but first of all you have to scan your account and find the malicious files. Then you can analyze the logs and see how the guy got in.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, Thank you very much for this precious informations, I installed maldet that uses clam av, and have done the scan but only clam av that found this :

Comment: 1- /home/mydomaine/mail/new/...,S=3004,W=3071:Js.Downloader.Nemucod-6210215-1 FOUND
2- Txt.Downloader.Nemucod-6283129-0 FOUND
3- Email.Phishing.VOF2-6314030-0 FOUND
--- in the same folder
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 6314112
Engine version: 0.99.2
Scanned directories: 59709
Scanned files: 558629
Infected files: 47
Data scanned: 7195.93 MB
Data read: 14871.08 MB (ratio 0.48:1)
Time: 4260.689 sec (71 m 0 s)
---
And I removed them all

Comment: and today I found :
May 26 15:33:23 server dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 2 secs): user=<*.xyz>, method=PLAIN, rip=207.154.218.182, lip=172.31.1.100, session=<W9iuDm9QErPPmtq2>
May 26 15:33:29 server dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 6 secs): user=<*.xyz*>, method=PLAIN, rip=207.154.218.182, lip=172.31.1.100, session=<Rc7NDm9QTLPPmtq2>
May 26 15:33:39 server dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 10 secs): user=<@*.xyz>, method=PLAIN, rip=207.154.218.182, lip=172.31.1.100, session=<gDUiD29QxLPPmtq2>
& many...

Comment: Those were just emails... You should scan the public_html/ folder inside of /home/cpanelusername

Comment: 2nd part consists of most probably bruteforce attempts to login via email (pop3 in your case). CSF will block them after an amount of tries, depending on how you configured it